Debug particular dotnet sdk command with custom repo build
I am wannabe OSS collaborator, when I glanced upon several OSS projects I decided to try fix some issue inside dotnet sdk solution, from GitHub described as a "good first issue" and "help wanted"
So I found one, about adding an alias to existing sln command.
I am unable to force the dotnet executable to perform it's job using my selected arguments (dotnet sln sdk.sln list) - instead it just runs with "dotnet" and that's it.
After I followed all previous steps till this one - And here is the point where it seems at least foggy for me - I can debug "dotnet" command. This will cause all of the commands to be parsed in Program.cs, it gonna invoke the parsing result so it should be fine, but...
Let me show by the screens:

In the Dogfood context, I am running a command to start the process: step 1
In my VS2022 Preview started as described in here I attach the debugger to the process shown in the step 1.
I type Enter on the Command prompt from step 1.
dotnet sdk is running the command, but it runs "dotnet" command solely, instead of running the command I want it to run ("dotnet sln sdk.sln list" command)

I think I'll mange further on from that point after I will find a way to debug the particular command, not the root one (as for now)
SOLVED
I found solution, on how to debug those commands, as I've found out in
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.DebugHelper.HandleDebugSwitch() method - this --debug flag has to be the first argument provided for the dotnet command to make this working as expected, source file
So, in order to debug for example a "sln list" subcommand:
dotnet --debug sln sdk.sln list
and all goes as expected :)
Issue can be closed

Please fix the markdown broken link.
